# Google Cloud Platform: Ubuntu VM won’t run tasks indefinitely

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform

I’m having trouble running background tasks in an Ubuntu VM on Google Cloud Compute. When I start the task it runs for some time, but eventually it always stops. Normally this after about 20-30 minutes, but sometimes it lasts an hour.
Things I’ve tried:

- Running the task directly
- Running the task in the primary terminal with nohup
- Running the task in a new terminal using screen
- Running the task in a new terminal using screen and nohup
- Each of the above with sudo

Surely there must be a way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the task produce any logs to determine why the command fails?

Comment: @CraigWatson No, there are the nohup logs but they don't appear to contain anything specific to the task stopping.

Comment: What is the task?

Comment: @CosmicOssifrage I'm trying to run a discord bot, which is basically just a python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a fundamental misunderstanding on my part. I was using the Google Platform cloud shell thinking I was connecting to the full VM but it's not.

On GCP you have to SSH using a separate client (any SSH client it seems). The cloud shell seemed really useful but unfortunately it's fundamentally not the VM.

Comment: In https://console.cloud.google.com/ you can find your VM and a link to ssh to it through a web application. There is also an option to display a `gcloud` command which will ssh to your VM (by invoking an external ssh client with the correct arguments). That `gcloud` command should also work inside Cloud Shell if you prefer to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should realistically be running this script/task/command as a daemon.

As you're using Ubuntu, I would recommend `systemd`. There are several ways of configuring a service to suit your needs, but something like this should suffice [[doc]](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/creating-systemd-service-files). It's worth noting that for security reasons, your bot should be running as its own user, with only the permissions it needs to function.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Discord Bot
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=mybot
WorkingDirectory=/home/mybot
ExecStart=/home/mybot/bin/mybot --option=123
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You can learn more about the configuration options for `systemd` using the [online documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).

Comment: Thanks for this, but it seems Google Cloud VMs aren’t set up with systems

Comment: @IanNewson the cloud platform has nothing to do with it - any Ubuntu version above 16.04 uses systemd. Docs: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Comment: I have realised my misunderstanding and it was a GCP thing. I've posted an answer myself.